# "HTTP 405" when creating Servlet? (doPost and doGet implemented)

Tags: java, servlets

I have a servlet named HelloServlet..

```
    import java.io.*;
    import javax.servlet.*;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
    public class HelloServlet extends HttpServlet
    {
public void doGet(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response)
throws ServletException, IOException
{


        response.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter pw = response.getWriter();
        pw.println("<html>");
        pw.println("<head>");
        pw.println("<title> Hello World </title>");
        pw.println("</head>");
        pw.println("<body>");
        pw.println("<h1> Hello, World!</h1>");
        pw.println("</body>");
        pw.println("</html>");
        pw.close();




}
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
throws ServletException, IOException
{
    doGet(request, response);
}
    }
```

I compile it to a `.class` file and i place it in my tomcat directory under `C:/tomcat/webapps/ALTest1/WEB-INF/classes/` - I made the servlet mapping (I put the url-pattern as `/hi`)  and servlet entry for it in `C:/tomcat/webapps/ALTest1/WEB-INF/web.xml`

Everything works fine but when I go to my browser to access it at `http://localhost:8080/ALTest1/hi` I get an error message saying:

```
HTTP STATUS 405 - HTTP METHOD GET is not supported by this URL
```

...which is strange, because I have BOTH `doPost` and `doGet` methods in my `HelloServlet.class` file. So, even if `doGet` isn't supported, I have the doPost method to take care of POST yet it still isn't working.

Comment: Maybe it's the late hour, but I don't see a problem yet. Care to show us the servlet mapping?

Comment: Sure thing! My Servlet mapping is:     <?xml version="1.0"?>
<web-app>
<servlet>
 <servlet-name>HiEverybody</servlet-name>
 <servlet-class>HelloServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
 <servlet-name>HiEverybody</servlet-name>
 <url-pattern>/hi</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>



</web-app>

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
 public void doGet(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response)
```

That should have been HttpServletRequest and HttpServletResponse, just like in doPost.

Always use @Override, that would have told you about this error.

Comment: Bravo!  Good eyes (I missed the arguments mismatch!).  And excellent advice about "@Override".  Great response!

Answer (score 0):

It seems there is no package for your servlet java class. For normal java programs running throw main methord, if there is no package specified the java class is in default package. However, for web application, you need to specify the package name in the web.xml.

Comment: How can i do that? I Am new to servlets